# URL prefix to process.env

Tags: vue.js, nginx, url, redirect, strapi

I am developing a new platform website, which should allow to easily make new websites using a headless CMS (Strapi).

For the front part, I am using vuejs with nuxtjs, and for the api, using Strapi: the data is stored in a database.
-> Each company has its own database.
-> The front part is the same for all companies
Only the database need to be changed to switch from one company to another.

For now, I only need to change .env file (in the api project) with DATABASE_NAME=companyA to DATABASE_NAME=companyB to swicth from a website to another one.
Here is database.json file:

```
"database":"${process.env.DATABASE_NAME||'companyA'}"
```

But I would like to get this url prefix in the frontend url (example:)

```
http://127.0.0.1/companya/....
http://127.0.0.1/companyb/....
```

To be able to send it to the api url prefix as well maybe) and know which database I should use.

Could you please tell me if you have an idea on how this could work? I could share my code but i think it's more of a theoric question I have now...

Answer (score 0):

With [VueRouter](https://router.vuejs.org/) 
you can set a path like:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/companya', name: 'companya', component: MyPage },
  { path: '/companyb', name: 'companyb', component: MyPage },
];
```

then in `MyPage.vue` you can look at the current route:

```
created () {
    switch (this.$route.name) {
      case 'companyA':
        // switch connection
        break;
      case 'companyB':
        // switch connection
        break;
    }
  },
```